# como agrupar resultado mysql while dentro da table html php

Tags: php, table, while

Boa tarde alguém pode me dar uma luz estou tentando organizar os dados dentro do while, 
hoje consigo pegar os dados e colocar na table normal so que meu problema é quando tem muitos itens dentro de um volume dai fica repetido um monte de vez o nome do volume, peso e dimensão.
A ideia seria agrupar o nome do volume peso e dimensão e os resultados repetidor e fazer um  com a quantidade de informações agrupadas como na foto em anexo. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que linguagem de programação vais usar para isso?

Comment: amigo uso php e mysql

Comment: Ok, juntei essa tag à pergunta para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Podes partilhar o código que já tens?

Comment: tentou usar um distinct com group by no select?

Comment: <?
     while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql_vol)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
<!-- Começo lista itens do volume -->     
     <td width="auto"><? echo $linha ['pro_cod'];?></td>
     <td width="auto"><? echo $linha ['pro_nome'];?><br><font class="desc"><i><? echo $linha ['pro_descricao'];?></i></font></td>
     <td width="auto"><? echo $linha ['vi_quantidade'];?></td>
     <td width="auto"><? echo $linha ['med_nome'];?></td>
     <td width="auto" rowspan=""><? echo $linha ['vol_nome'];?></td>
     <td width="auto" rowspan=""><? echo $linha ['vol_peso'];?> kg</td>

Comment: (SELECT 
produto.pro_cod,
produto.pro_nome,
produto.pro_descricao,
SUM(volume_itens.vi_quantidade) AS vi_quantidade,
medida.med_nome,
volume.vol_id,
volume.vol_nome,
volume.vol_peso,
volume.vol_altura,
volume.vol_largura,
volume.vol_comprimento
FROM volume
LEFT JOIN volume_itens ON volume.vol_id = volume_itens.vi_vol_id
LEFT JOIN produto ON volume_itens.vi_pro_id = produto.pro_id
LEFT JOIN medida ON produto.pro_med_id = medida.med_id
WHERE vol_sai_id = '$id'
GROUP BY pro_id, vol_nome
ORDER BY vol_nome AND pro_nome ASC)

Comment: tentei mas nao deu certo continua repetindo

Comment: e como o distinct?

Comment: sem chance ja tentei.... na realidade esta acontecendo assim

Comment: nao vai ja tentei.... 
esta puxando as informaçoes certa do db.
meu priblema e na hr de jogar na tela q quero organizar

na imagens a while puxa 3 resoltados assim

id, cod, produto, qtd, un, volume, peso e dimensao

1, 10, produto 1, 100, Un, Caixa 1, 10Kg, 50 x 43 x 55 cm
2, 13, wwww, 1, Un, Caixa 1, 10Kg, 50 x 43 x 55 cm
3, 10, produto 1, 200, Un, Caixa 2, 15Kg, 23 x 54 x 82 cm

agora como faço pra fazer ficar como a tabela da parte de baixo da imagem.

Comment: Você pode postar o HTML de uma das imagens para saber qual estilo está aplicado a tabela? Classe, id etc...

Comment: O peso da caixa 1 não deveria ser 20 Kg ?

Answer (score 3):

**Tabela de exemplo**

[image: Tabela de exemplo]

**Codigo PHP**

```
$td1="";
$td2="";
$td3="";
$Linha="";
$linhaFim="";
$result="";
$pesoOld="";
$dimensaoOld="";
$dimensaoOld2="";
$z="1";

$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB");

$sqlm = ("SELECT * FROM dados order by id asc");

$resultado = mysqli_query($link,$sqlm);

echo "<table border=\"1\"><tr><th>Cod.:</th><th>Produto</th><th>Qtd.:</th><th>Un.:</th><th>Volume:</th><th>Peso:</th><th>Dimensao: A.L.C.</th></tr>\n";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
 $cod=$row["cod"];
  $produto=$row["produto"];
   $qtd=$row["qtd"];
    $un=$row["un"];
     $volume=$row["volume"];
      $peso=$row["peso"];
       $dimensao=$row["dimensao"];

        $Linha = "<tr>\n<td>".$cod."</td>\n<td>".$produto."</td>\n<td>".$qtd."</td>\n<td>".$un."</td>\n";

        $td1 = "<td>".$volume."</td>\n";

        $td2 = "<td class=".$volume.">".$peso."</td>\n";

        $td3 = "<td class=".$volume.">".$dimensao."</td>\n";    

        $linhaFim = "\n</tr>\n";

        $result .= $Linha.$td1.$td2.$td3.$linhaFim;   
}

$ocorrencias = substr_count($result,"<td>Caixa");

for ($k = 1; $k < $ocorrencias; $k++) {
    $num = substr_count($result,"<td>Caixa ".$k."</td>");
    if ($num > 1){

        $result =  preg_replace("#<td>Caixa ".$k."</td>#", "<td rowspan=\"".$num."\">Caixa ".$k."</td>", $result,1);
        $result =  preg_replace("#<td>Caixa ".$k."</td>#", "", $result,$num-1);
        $volume="Caixa ".$k;

        $consultar = "SELECT volume,dimensao, peso, SUM(peso) AS subt FROM (SELECT volume,dimensao,peso FROM dados Where volume='$volume' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $num) AS tabelaSubt";
        $resulta = mysqli_query($link, $consultar);

            while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulta)){
                $peso = $item["peso"];
                $subt = $item['subt'];
                $dimensao = $item['dimensao'];
                $volume = $item['volume'];

                $dimensaoTot="23 x 54 x 82 cm";

                //volume para 2 itens de 23 x 54 x 82 cm
                $dimensaoTot2="?? x ?? x ?? cm";

                $result =  preg_replace("#<td class=".$volume.">".$peso."</td>#", "<td rowspan=\"".$num."\">".$subt." Kg</td>", $result,1);
                $result =  preg_replace("#<td class=".$volume.">".$peso."</td>#", "", $result,$num-1);
                $result =  preg_replace("#<td class=".$volume.">".$pesoOld."</td>#", "", $result,$num-1);

                $result = preg_replace("#<td class=".$volume.">50 x 43 x 55 cm</td>#", "<td rowspan=\"".$num."\">".$dimensaoTot."</td>", $result,1);
                $result = preg_replace("#<td class=".$volume.">50 x 43 x 55 cm</td>#", "", $result,$num-1);
                $result = preg_replace("#<td class=".$volume.">".$dimensaoOld."</td>#", "", $result,1);

                $result = preg_replace("#<td class=".$volume.">23 x 54 x 82 cm</td>#", "<td rowspan=\"".$num."\">".$dimensaoTot2."</td>", $result,1);
                $result = preg_replace("#<td class=".$volume.">23 x 54 x 82 cm</td>#", "", $result,$num-1);
                $result = preg_replace("#<td class=".$volume.">".$dimensaoOld2."</td>#", "", $result,1);

                $pesoOld=$peso;
                $dimensaoOld=$dimensao;
                $dimensaoOld2=$dimensao;
            }
    }
}

echo $result;
echo "</table>";
```

> Essa é uma rotina básica e que pode ser incrementada de acordo com as necessidades visto que a pergunta não deu todas as variações possíveis